# Can't see my hybrid mobile app to debug Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, hybrid-mobile-app

I have done all the necessary things to allow me to debug my app on an Android device, by allowing debugging etc but I cannot see the app. I only am able to see the web sessions..

[Available to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcAiA.png)

I am having issues with the Samsung Galaxy S5 and S6 not allowing my app to load any content. I just get a white screen with my loading gif spinning. I have read many forums and members have pointed towards permission issues on the new android versions which is causing my app to not load..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For hybrid mobile apps, I needed to add this snippet of code to the config.xml file which allowed me to debug the app:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
  <application android:debuggable="true" />
</gap:config-file>
```